# Http(s) request responds with garbage characters

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to send a request to a website to get some data from it. However, the response is garbage characters like:

```
Ì 3ú¢¸<N¤@H±ü>§#Fe®¡+K·fÐcÄ±aOqâò;'Êù!°â<rº\¼YDóß1K`òúüb¨ÑTcíÆ
```

This only happens for reposes with data in it, and errors also work fine.
The response is supposed to look like this (from browser request):
`{"d":[{"__type":"CalendarTransport:http:...","activityId":2662,"activityImportIdentifier":null,"activityType":1,"allDay":false,"attendanceMode":1,....`

Here is my code

```
        try
        {
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection;
            httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https", redacted, redacted).openConnection();

            try
            {
                httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: oh no (3) it's a " + e.toString());
            }
            httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "*/*");
            httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", new DomainCookies(redacted).toRequestHeader());
            httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream os = httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
            osw.write(redacted);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
            os.close(); 

            StringBuilder mssg = new StringBuilder();
            DataInputStream inputStream;

            int status = httpsURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (status != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                inputStream = new DataInputStream(httpsURLConnection.getErrorStream());
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: HTTP error");
            }
            else
            {
                inputStream = new DataInputStream(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: HTTP OK");
            }
            try
            {
                for(int c = inputStream.read(); inputStream.available() != 0; c = inputStream.read())
                {
                    mssg.append((char)c);
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + mssg);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: oh no (1) it's a " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Oh no it's a " + e.toString());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Oh no it's a " + e.toString());
        }
```

The browser can get the response fine, do it must be something I am doing (or android, but I doubt that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by getting rid of this line:

```
httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
```

Your code is not handling those forms of data encoding, so do not ask the server to encode the data that way.

Beyond that... it is 2018. Stop using `HttpsURLConnection`. Use something more modern and less error-prone, such as [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp).

Comment: It works, now thanks (can accept answer in 9 minutes??)